# Glue records for sub domains?

Tags: domain-name-system, glue-record

Let's say I own example.com

I created an A record called dns.example.com then point it at a nameserver.
On the nameserver I gave it the name ns1.dns.example.com and also dns.example.com

Now I'm confused. Do I create glue records of ns1.dns.example.com or dns.example.com? Do I also still need the A records for my dns.example.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need glue records if the NS records for a domain point to hostnames within that domain. For example, this would not need glue-records:

```
testing.example.com:
NS = ns1.infra.example.com.
NS = ns2.infra.example.com.
```

Where, this one would need glue-records:

```
testing.example.com:
NS = ns1.testing.example.com.
NS = ns2.testing.example.com.
```

In that case, the glue records go into the `example.com` domain.

```
example.com:
[...]
testing.example.com.     IN NS ns1.testing.example.com.
testing.example.com.     IN NS ns2.testing.example.com.
ns1.testing.example.com. IN  A 172.16.202.152
ns2.testing.example.com. IN  A 172.12.9.11
```

Comment: I think I understand it now. I'm using gandi for my dns managment. I went into glue record to add the ns1.testing.example.com  and after a few 12 hours it didn't work, I also didn't see it in my zone file. I assume it is because I don't have a NS record. Now I've gone into example.com and added the NS and A record. Also have the glue record. Hopefully I'll see it working in the next few hours!

Comment: the two **A** records shown are missing a **.**-dot after the domain; if its missing it will result in the domain being interpreted as `ns1.testing.example.com.example.com` @lbanz in the gandi glue management, you don't need the trailing dot.

Comment: @pete thank you, it is all working now. I couldn't get it to work at first because I didn't realise gandi is using relative path. So using ns1.testing.example.com. didn't work and I changed it to I use ns1.testing Now all seems to be working.

Comment: @lbanz didn't work even without the trailing dot? i have mine setup with the full ns domain and no issue, although my servers are only one sub deep. either way, glad it works